# d3 line chart and dates values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to make a line chart with d3.js using values from csvfile.

I have followed a few examples on how to make charts using d3. However, the result from this line chart isn't accurate.

[image]

This is an example of the data i'm working with:

```
dates,count
17-dic-12,1
18-abr-13,1
11-oct-13,1
12-dic-13,1
08-jul-14,4
30-jul-14,4
01-ago-14,1
22-oct-14,3
30-oct-14,1
24-nov-14,1
02-dic-14,1
24-dic-14,1
14-ene-15,4
15-ene-15,1
22-ene-15,2
12-feb-15,1
17-abr-15,1
24-jun-15,1
15-jul-15,2
25-ago-15,1
28-ago-15,1
31-ago-15,1
01-sep-15,1
17-sep-15,1
24-dic-15,1
```

This is the code I used:

```
var m = [25, 50, 25, 50],
    w = 700 - m[1] - m[3],
    h = 400 - m[0] - m[2];
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, w]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([h, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom').ticks(5);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left').ticks(5);
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.dates); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); });
var svg = d3.select('#graph')
    .classed("svg-container", true)
    .append('svg')
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 850 1000")
    .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + m[3] + ',' + m[0] + ')');
d3.csv('datesdata.csv', function(error, dataset) {
    dataset.forEach(function(d) {
        d.dates = formatDate(d.dates);
        d.count = +d.count;
    });
    x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.dates; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.count; })]);
    svg.append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', valueline(dataset));
    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + h + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .call(yAxis);
});
```

I tried to improve this code changing `formatDate` variable, but the result is the same.

Is there an option to improve this chart?

Comment: `console.log()` the result of `formatDate(d.dates)`. It's probably coming up blank for any month names that are not in English (`dic`, `abr`, `ago`) because d3 doesn't know about those. Need to rename your months, either in the CSV or in javascript using a hash, or — and this looks complicated — you can supply d3 with a locale object that defines the Spanish month abbreviations. To figure out how to do that last one, you'll need to dive into the d3 source.

Comment: Yes almost certainly an issue with the date parsing. Just convert the date strings to ISO format and it will probably work.

Comment: Exactly! Just as @meetamit said, I changed dates to english format. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your data has wrong definition. Maybe you're spanish but D3 Time Format just recognize english months. Change your months like so:

```
ene --> jan  *
feb --> feb
mar --> mar
abr --> apr  *
may --> may
jun --> jun
jul --> jul
ago --> aug  *
sep --> sep
oct --> oct
nov --> nov
dic --> dec  *
```

And your data become:

```
dates,count
17-dec-12,1
18-apr-13,1
11-oct-13,1
12-dec-13,1
08-jul-14,4
30-jul-14,4
01-aug-14,1
22-oct-14,3
30-oct-14,1
24-nov-14,1
02-dec-14,1
24-dec-14,1
14-jan-15,4
15-jan-15,1
22-jan-15,2
12-feb-15,1
17-apr-15,1
24-jun-15,1
15-jul-15,2
25-aug-15,1
28-aug-15,1
31-aug-15,1
01-sep-15,1
17-sep-15,1
24-dec-15,1
```

[Here the working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/uhpr4o4osV6Wnw10QuyH?p=preview)